# LibericaJdk 11 with openjfx

Tags: intellij-idea, java-11, openjfx

I am trying to build a JavaFX application based on LibericaJDK in Intellj which is supposed to support JavaFX/OpenJFX). So I do not declare any such dependencies. But the build fails, stating it cand find Javafx related packages. Should it be possible to compile a JavaFX application out-of-the-box with LibericaJDK? Or is it an intellij setting I am missing?

Comment: Have you installed JavaFX? It is no longer part of the JDK and has to be manually installed.

Comment: According to https://bell-sw.com/pages/liberica-release-notes-11.0.3/ the jdk should already be bundled with JavaFX. I quote: "Windows x86_64, Windows x86, Mac, Linux x86_64, Linux x86 and Linux ARMv7 distributions contain OpenJFX 11."

Comment: Liberica is provided in several "packages": lite, standard and full. Only full contains OpenJFX, as I understand it. Do you have the "full" version?

Comment: @BasLeijdekkers thank you I just smacked the download button which gave me the standard. This is the answer to my problem!

Comment: I have added it as an answer as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Download the "Full" package of Liberica JDK. Liberica JDK is provided in 3 different packages: lite, standard and full. Only Full contains OpenJFX.